# How to login into a linux ssh server built by windows docker remotely?

Tags: docker, ssh, server

I have build the image to run a container on windows. 
I run the container on my windows just like `docker run --privileged=true -id -host -p 123:22 .....` and I can login into the container with `ssh -p 123 user_name@127.0.0.1` on the host Windows computer.

But when I failed to login into the server remotely on another computer. I use `telnet host_machine_ip 123` and have no response.

So what should I do to login into the ssh server remotely? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have started ssh server into your container? Can you show your `Dockerfile`, or result of `docker top <container_name>`

Comment: Port 123 is blocked by the firewall I'd guess. See if you can configure it to allow connections remotely. (Or turn the firewall off briefly to investigate, but don't leave it off.)

Comment: @Rup You are write, Thank you. I turn the firewall off and then I can login into the ssh server. But it must be in the same local network. So, If I want to login into from another network, what should I do?

Comment: Great! Please add a firewall exception and turn it back on rather than just leaving it off, if you haven’t already.

Comment: @Rup I follow your suggestion. And I am looking for the way to login from WAN